# How to add JS and CSS file in web page based on parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a static html page which provides map based on selection from google map and openstreet map. I added Javascript and CSS file of both maps in the head tag. The problem is that if I only use Google map, the Javascript and CSS files for openstreet map are also loaded. How can I load Javascript and CSS file based on the map selection?